# When is a transaction valid?

Tags: iri-node, transaction, validation

Which [parts of a transaction](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/100/10) need to have what value in order for it to be stored and broadcast by the IRI?

I know that there are some ***bundle level*** conditions like

- valid signature
- sum of all values is 0
- ... **?**

and some ***transaction level*** conditions like

- POW was done
- ... **?**

I've also heard something about timestamps needing to be within a certain range. **True?**

---

**What other conditions are there?

Is there another *level* i.e. what happens to transactions that have trunk/branch transactions that don't exist (yet)?

Where can I find these checks in the IRI's source code?

I know this is a long shot but is there any documentation on it?**

Comment: see https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/why-arent-timestamps-validated

Comment: If there are no levels, how is "valid signature" and "sum of all values in bundle is 0" checked? (You didn't mention it in your answer, otherwise very nice answer - thanks)

Comment: See also https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/40/what-kind-of-invalid-transactions-are-transported-by-the-network-and-appear-o for validations that happen after the transaction is accepted (and that validate the bundle). Note that these validations do not prevent the transaction from being transported by the network, but they prevent it from being chosen as a tip (and therefore confirmed).

Comment: @mihi Thanks! That's exactly what i was missing. Now everything makes sense again :+1:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Which parts of a transaction need to have what value in order for it to be stored and broadcast by the IRI?**

In the IRI, packets are received in the [UDPReceiver](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/UDPReceiver.java#L84) and then forwarded to the Node for processing. There is also a TCPReceiver (seldom used) and the packets follow the same process.

If the packet comes from a recognized sender (neighbor), the packet is processed.

If the packet is not a duplicate as determined by its presence in the `recentSeenBytes`, the packet is loaded into a `TransactionViewModel` for inspection, validation, storage and caching. If the packet is a duplicate, then it is ignored.

You can find the relevant code by looking for [preProcessReceivedData](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L223) in the IRI `Node.java` file and follow the process when you find this line:

```
TransactionValidator.runValidation(receivedTransactionViewModel, transactionValidator.getMinWeightMagnitude());
```

**Transactions are checked to make sure:**

1. [The Hash calculates properly](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L254).
2. [The transaction is dated no older than the last `Snapshot` and no
   newer than 2 hours into the future](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/TransactionValidator.java#L76).
3. The attachments must also be dated correctly (same as #2).
4. The transaction must meet the [Minimum Weight Magnitude](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/TransactionValidator.java#L97) hard-coded in
   the IRI node software.

It is then cached in `receiveQueue` and then stored in the local `tangle` database [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L384) as part of the gossip run-up routine.

If it has not been previously stored, [the senders IP is also logged along with the arrival time](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L391).

It is then added to the [broadcastQueue](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L401) and to make sure the rest of the network is notified about the transactions existence, [the broadcaster thread](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/network/Node.java#L492) picks it up and sends it to all the neighbors.

**Are all validated transactions provided as tips to other users in the '[getTips](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/service/API.java#L285)' statement?**

Yes. First, all received transactions as validated above are added to the [tips](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/TransactionValidator.java#L217). These are known as non-solid tips.

When the API `getTips` statement is called, they are added to the tips provided [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/controllers/TipsViewModel.java#L43).

### Rationale

The reason for these checks is first, to make sure it conforms to the proof of work anti-spam measure of the network (the Hash and Minimum Weight Magnitude checks), and second, to make sure that a reasonable bound is established to consider a transaction too old or too new to be gossiped.

Those checks are generally thwarted by the fact that POW can be [pre-computed](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1874/what-prevents-someone-from-using-a-precomputed-pow-spam-attack-against-the-netwo), computed very easily via FPGA (or other), and furthermore because the time on each transaction is self-reported.

At the stage of receiving a transaction, because the node is not aware of missing transactions that it has not been notified of, a received transaction can be fictitious and that fact cannot be determined upon receipt.

It is only with passing time that it will fall away as `evicted` because it can not be confirmed to reference a network `Milestone` transaction and is displaced by other received transactions. Regardless, it still consumes space in the local database and will make its rounds throughout the network.

The Milestone is absolutely essential because even if a transaction has tips that refer to many tips (long chain of transactions giving the appearance of validity), the reality is that an attacker can also construct this chain of transactions and then submit it to the network. The ultimate truth to the validity of a transaction is whether or not it references a Coordinator issued Milestone transaction.

Comment: Regarding concerns raised in last paragraphs: [local modifiers in the tangle](https://assets.ctfassets.net/r1dr6vzfxhev/4p2Jh4jQzYwmQSqScgKW2G/6bd776742d48e6a44fca66845e956e8e/Local_Modifiers_in_the_Tangle.pdf) is suggesting an approach to mitigate the effect of precomputed side-tangle attack. (in 2 words: the idea is to take into account the appearance timestamp to penalize transactions with suspicious timestamp/attachment-timestamp in the random walk)